# ClassLoader always returns null when called from within a jar

Tags: java, maven, classloader

I ran into library loading problems after creating a jar from my code via maven. I use intelliJ idea on Ubuntu. I broke the problem down to this situation:

Calling the following code from within idea it prints the path correctly.

```
package com.myproject;

public class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File classpathRoot = new File(Starter.class.getResource("/").getPath());
        System.out.println(classpathRoot.getPath());
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
/home/ted/java/myproject/target/classes
```

When I called `mvn install` and try to run it from command line using the following command I'm getting a `NullPointerException` since `class.getResource()` returns `null`:

```
cd /home/ted/java/myproject/target/
java -cp myproject-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.myproject.Starter
```

same for calling:

```
cd /home/ted/java/myproject/target/
java -Djava.library.path=. -cp myproject-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.myproject.Starter
```

It doesn't matter if I use `class.getClassLoader().getRessource("")` instead. Same problem when accessing single files inside of the target directory instead via `class.getClassLoader().getRessource("file.txt")`.

I want to use this way to load native files in the same directory (not from inside the jar). What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classpath loading mechanism in the JVM is highly extensible, so it's often hard to guarantee a single method that would work in all cases. e.g. What works in your IDE may not work when running in a container because your IDE and your container probably have highly specialized class loaders with different requirements.

You could take a two tiered approach. If the method above fails, you could get the classpath from the system properties, and scan it for the jar file you're interested in and then extract the directory from that entry.

e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = findJarLocation("jaxb-impl.jar");
    System.out.println(f);
}

public static File findJarLocation(String entryName) {

    String pathSep = System.getProperty("path.separator");

    String[] pathEntries = System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(pathSep);
    for(String entry : pathEntries) {
        File f = new File(entry);
        if(f.getName().equals(entryName)) {
            return f.getParentFile();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```